# How do you calculate two alias columns in a View

Tags: sql, alias

```
SELECT     DATASET, BLOCKID, CATEGORY, TONNES * t100 AS True_Tonnes, VOLUME * t100 AS True_Volume, g100 AS Grade
FROM         dbo.tblPTEvaluationRep_100ppm
```

I want to calculate True_Tonnes * Grade and alias it AS 'Metal' in the same View table I am creating.

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
SELECT DATASET,
       BLOCKID,
       CATEGORY,
       TONNES * t100 AS True_Tonnes,
       VOLUME * t100 AS True_Volume,
       g100 AS Grade,
       --
       tonnes * t100 * g100 as Metal   --> this
       -------------   ----    -----
       True_Tonnes     Grade   Alias   --> explanation
  FROM dbo.tblPTEvaluationRep_100ppm
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot re-use aliases in the `SELECT`.  You have four options:

- Repeat the expressions.
- Use a subquery.
- Use a CTE.
- Use a lateral join.

In SQL Server, the last method uses `APPLY`:

```
SELECT p.DATASET, p.BLOCKID, p.CATEGORY,
       v.True_Tonnes, v.True_Volume, v.Grade,
       (v.True_Tonnes * v.Grade) as Metal 
FROM dbo.tblPTEvaluationRep_100ppm p
     (VALUES (p.TONNES * t100, p.VOLUME * p.t100, g100)
     ) v(True_Tonnes, True_Volume, Grade);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query

SELECT 
  DATASET,
  BLOCKID,
  CATEGORY,
  TONNES * t100 AS True_Tonnes,
  VOLUME * t100 AS True_Volume,
  g100 AS Grade,tonnes * t100 * g100 as Metal 
FROM dbo.tblPTEvaluationRep_100ppm